# How to handle Mqtt Publish aws-iot exceptions on ESP32?

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, esp32, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I'm using an ESP32 in the aws cloud (Iot-Core) and afer a few hours connected, the device simply cannot publish in the MQTT topic anymore. I'm using Arduino IDE. I would like to know how can I map the Publish / Subscribe errors on ESP32 to understand the real reasons and how to handle them. Currently I'm restarting the device and the connection keep working until a period of time.

Comment: Hi Sidney. Please edit your post and provide the code you have and the exact error messages or exceptions that you see, console output etc. Ideally in the form of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or something as close to it as it makes sense in your case.

Comment: Based on what you described, the problem is likely not caused by the MQTT, but by your program's memory leaks or improper use of memory. But until we see your code, we can only speculate...